# new object is created or not?

Tags: java, static-methods

I am reading *Effective Java* by Joshua Bloch. It confuses me in the item 1, where it states

> A second advantage of static factory method is that, unlike constructors, they are not required to create a new object each time time they're invoked.

Isn't the static factory method meant to create a new object each time it is invoked?

```
//constructor
Orange(){
}

//static factory method
static Orange staticFactoryMethod(){
    return new Orange;
}
```

Won't calling either the constructor or the `staticFactoryMethod` create an instance of `Orange`?

```
Orange orange=new Orange();

Orange orange=Orange.staticFactoryMethod();
```

Comment: I think he's getting at the idea that because a factory is an abstraction, it's free to do *whatever* it wants; maybe it returns a cached copy, or an object from a pool that was allocated on start-up. It *may* just end up calling `new Orange()`, but it is not *required* to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static factory does not always need to create a new object.
You can have this:

```
static Orange staticFactoryMethod(){
    return new Orange();
}
```

But you can also have something like

```
static Orange staticFactoryMethod(){
    Orange o = ... //find an orange in a basket of available oranges that has been already initialized
    return o;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't the static factory method is mean to create a new object each time it is invoked?

No.  The purpose of a factory method is to return a *suitable* object.  That object might be an object that was created earlier.  It all depends on the intended semantics of the factory, and of the objects.  For instance, it the objects are immutable and their *object identity* has no special significance, then sharing instances can be a worthwhile optimization.

For example, the `Integer.valueOf(int)` method returns an `Integer` method that may (for small integers) have been created and used previously.  This has the advantage of reducing the number of `Integer` instances that are created ... and need to be garbage collected when they are finished with.

You could also argued that `String.intern(String)` is a form of factory method, though it has the unusual property that (in recent implementations) it never allocates new strings.

A third example is a thread or connection pool which tries to recycle objects that have been returned to the pool.

By contrast, if the "client" of your API has to use `new` to create instances, there is no opportunity for your API to do this kind of thing.  That is Bloch's point.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `Integer.valueOf(int i).` If `i` is within the range -128 to 127 this method will not create a new Integer object but return a value from cache.