# Private Constructor initialized by a public method

Tags: java, constructor, public-method

I came cross a class with private constructor but the object is returned by another public method by call to the private constructor. What may be the advantage of such a construct when we could have made the constructor public?

```
public final class TokenTable {

    static public int errorToken = 0; 
    static public int timesToken = 1;
    static public int divToken = 2;
    static public int plusToken = 11;
    ......
    ......

    private final HashMap<String, Integer> keywordMap = new HashMap();
    private final HashMap<String, Integer> operationMap = new HashMap();

    private TokenTable() {

        operationMap.put("*", timesToken);
        operationMap.put("/", divToken);
        operationMap.put("+", plusToken);
        ....



    }


    static public TokenTable getInstance() {

            LexTokenTabInstance = new TokenTable();
            return LexTokenTabInstance;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have to say, i'm a bit disappointed that most of the answers here bring up singletons.  I guess it's the name of `getInstance()` (which is one of the most common names for a singleton getter)...but still.

Comment: @cHao If you aren't satisfied with the current answers, why don't you create your own? If you feel there is a better answer than those provided, I would be curious to read it.

Comment: @Supericy: Because there are two good ones here that already say pretty much what i would.  It's the others that depress me.

Comment: You can also take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620832/new-object-is-created-or-not/16620876#16620876 which is relevant to the static factory pattern.

Answer (score 6):

This is called the `Factory` pattern. Check out the description [here - Factory Design Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html).

There are several advantages:

- you can have multiple named factory methods to create different flavors of the object which can allow for overloading with the same set of parameter types
- you can return a singleton if appropriate or maybe return one of a cached set of instances
- if don't need to use `new`
- when using generics, the generic type is inferred by the compiler so don't need to use the `<>` operator
- you can return an interface instead of a concrete class
- allows for pre-constructor initialization (for example if init must be done prior to calling base class constructor)

To be clear, the above example it seems that it was done just as a "good practice" since none of the above capabilities was used (other than you don't have to use "new").

Comment: It should probably be noted that where you won't need any of these advantages, an ordinary, public constructor carries a bit less mental baggage.  ie: Don't go turning everything into a factory just cause it's spiffier.  :)

Answer (score 3):

This is called a factory method. A factory method has many advantages over a constructor:

- it has a name (and multiple factory methods may have different names)
- it allows returning a cached instance instead of a new instance
- it allows returning a subclass instance instead of the actual class
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage is that no one can create an instance, but using static `getInstance` method.

This way you can make sure only **one** instance is created, just as [Singelton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason for hiding a constructor of a class is to control how objects of that class are created. A common example of this is in the Singleton pattern, where only one object of a class is instantiated.

In order to police this, the user accesses a static method which will access the private constructor if the object isn't created, or else return a reference to the already created object:

```
public class SingletonDemo {
    private static volatile SingletonDemo instance = null;

    private SingletonDemo() {       }

    public static SingletonDemo getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                    synchronized (SingletonDemo.class){
                            if (instance == null) {
                                    instance = new SingletonDemo();
                            }
                  }
            }
            return instance;
    }
}
```

For other examples, look at Factory patterns in general: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to protect creation of multiple instance outside the class then you can create private constructor.
This is helpful creating a single instance.
**You can do it like(Eager loading):**

```
private static final TokenTable tokenTable = new TokenTable();

static public TokenTable getInstance() {

          return tokenTable;
    }
```

**Or, you can do it like(Lazy loading):**

```
private static TokenTable tokenTable;

static public TokenTable getInstance() {
         if(null == tokenTable){
         tokenTable = new TokenTable(); 
         }
          return tokenTable;
    }
```

Comment: Note, the lazy loading example is not thread-safe.  :P  You'd generally mark the function as `synchronized`, or explicitly synchronize on the class or something.

Comment: Ok Chao, Thanks for this valuable info.